# Disponibilizar download de arquivo do servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Existe uma funcionalidade de cadastrar os dados de um cliente.
O usuário seleciona um arquivo do computador dele, e este arquivo é importado para o servidor em uma pasta separada, sendo que esse arquivo pode ser um *PDF*, *JPEG*, *PNG*.

Existe uma tela de edição deste cliente, onde ele terá um botão para fazer o download deste documento. Minha dúvida é: **Como implementar a funcionalidade do download do arquivo armazenado no servidor?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assim:

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
{
    var caminhoDaImagem = /* Aqui você usa id que vem por parâmetro pra fazer alguma operação que seleciona o caminho da imagem de algum lugar */
    byte[] dadosArquivo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoDaImagem);
    return File(dadosArquivo, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg, "meuarquivo.jpg");
}
```

[Veja aqui os `MediaTypes` para imagens disponíveis nativamente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.image(v=vs.110).aspx).

Uso:

```
http://localhost:porta/MeuController/Download/1
```

Comment: amigo, no caso na linha  using (var fs = new FileStream(caminhoDaImagem))  ele me pede como parametro um FileMode, no meu caso que é para downlaod o correto é usar qual? FileMode.Open?

Comment: Exato. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: outra coisa, acusa erro em fs.ToArray(), diz que filestream nao possui um toarray

Comment: Sim, funcionaria pra `MemoryStream`, não pra `FileStream`. Veja minha edição.

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente porem o nome do arquivo esta vindo com o nome do meu método la na action tem como eu nomear o arquivo que esta baixando?

Comment: Sim, veja minha edição. O nome do arquivo é o terceiro argumento.

Comment: Prefiro esta resposta do que a outra por não deixar nenhum _stream_ aberto (mesmo que seja por pouco tempo). Mas ainda assim, não sei se é realmente necessário abrir o arquivo só pra isso. +1 =D

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado !

Answer (score 5):

Se o arquivo existe no disco e você sabe o caminho dele, seria melhor retorná-lo sem precisar se preocupar em abri-lo, certo?

```
public FileResult Download(int id) 
{
    string caminho = /*Buscar caminho do arquivo */;
    var result = new FilePathResult(caminho, "image/jpeg")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "nomeParaDownload.jpg"
    };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Entendo, mas nesse caso em disco vc diz no servidor correto ? ou na maquina da pessoa que subiu o arquivo ?

Comment: No servidor....

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !!

Answer (score 4):

Você já deve ter visto que os métodos dos controllers que atendem às requisições das páginas retornam objetos do tipo `ActionResult`.

Normalmente você retorna conteúdo HTML através do método `View` do próprio controller. Você pode mudar o tipo do retorno para um arquivo facilmente, basta retornar um objeto `FileStreamResult` ao invés de chamar o método `View`.

Segue a [documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx).

E um exemplo:

```
public ActionResult BoloDeFuba()
{
    FileStream arquivo = new FileStream(@"c:\bolo de fubá.doc");
    FileStreamResult download = new FileStreamResult(arquivo, "application/msword"); // O segundo parâmetro é o Mime type
    download.FileDownloadName = "bolo de fubá.doc";
    return download;
}
```

Note que o `FileStreamResult` recebe qualquer objeto do tipo `Stream`. Você pode montar um arquivo em memória ou carregar do banco de dados ao invés de carregar de uma pasta, quando lhe for necessário ou mais conveniente.

Comment: Jovem, `FileStream` implementa `IDisposable`. Boa prática usar `using` para não causar um pico de uso de memória na aplicação.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez valeu!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu fiquei com uma dúvida, pois fechar a `Stream` impediria seu correto retorno pelo controller. E de fato, testei e usar o `using` nesse caso provoca erro. Nesse caso especial, não precisamos nos preocupar, pois o método `FileStreamResult` chama o disposing da `stream` internamente. Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275764/does-filestreamresult-close-stream

Comment: Verdade, porque `FileStreamResult` supõe que sua conexão com o *stream* vai ficar aberta depois do retorno. Não acho essa abordagem boa pra arquivo normal.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !